# Key error when trying to vlookup pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to vlookup values of EW against AD.

Dataframe 1

```
    EW      
0   A  
1   BC
```

Dataframe 2

```
      AD     
0     A  
1     B  
2     BC
```

Then I run:

```
df3 = df1.insert(0, 'AD', df1['EW'].map(df2.set_index('EW')['AD']))
print (df1)
```

Expect output for df3:

```
      AD     
0     A  
1     NaNa  
2     BC
```

I keep getting: `KeyError: 'EW'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code error, come from the df2 do not have the columns name 'EW'

I will recommend using `isin` + `np.where`

```
df2.AD=np.where(df2.AD.isin(df1.EW),df2.AD,np.nan)
df2
Out[193]: 
    AD
0    A
1  NaN
2   BC
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are checking if the values in `df2.AD` are in `df1.EW`.  You can accomplish this with a left merge.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'EW':['A','BC']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'AD':['A','B','BC']})
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', left_on='AD', right_on='EW')[['EW']]
df3.rename(columns={'EW':'AD'})

# returns:
    EW
0    A
1  NaN
2   BC
```